# Result of Multiple Ajax requests, one depends on other Ajax Output

Tags: javascript, perl, reactjs, catalyst

I am developing a web application on Perl Catalyst and using ReactJS for the view, jQuery for AJAX, and JSX added as a script in the header.

I am able to fetch AJAX JSON data on a page and refresh the data every 10 seconds. We found this option we create on load on server to fetch data on every 10 seconds. This application is going to be used by a number of users together, so we autogenerate a key which will be incremented if any data is updated on that database table. We set this key on the rest, and it can be accessed by AJAX JSON.

I want to implement a React component which will check this autogenerated AJAX JSON key and will compare it to its previous value every 10 seconds. If they are not equal then it will call the other AJAX function or React component which will update the data on the view page, and older values will be replaced by new.

I have searched a lot but don't get the logic to implement this in ReactJS. Any logic or reference link will be helpful.

Comment: Why not check the incrementing key on the server side and not even require two separate calls?

Comment: thanks for comment,  that page in our app will run continuously and it will updated with from different  pages from different users, Currently, I don't have any idea how to implement this on each Ajax get request response on every 10 sec to avoid load on server. so we setup it separately.

Comment: You may wish to consider using something like flux or redux then and have your store implement the logic to only perform the ajax request if the token is updated.  I don't think this should be a difficult problem to solve if the application is designed correctly, so you may have a design problem here (which flux or redux should fix).  Otherwise, just expose your token somewhere it can be read by the code performing the ajax requests, and have it check the token before making the call...  or is your question about how to perform such a check or?

Comment: thanks Trevor Freeman,  yes you got my point, how to perform such a check ? Let me correct if I am wrong, Is this type of check is not possible in reactjs only and I have to use flux or redux for this.

Comment: No you don't have to use flux or redux, but they will just allow you to have a cleaner application design.  As far as I can understand, all you need to do is change your timer task to call your new ajax function every 10 seconds, and then when it receives its result (so in its success handler), check if the token has changed (vs a copy you have kept of the previous value), and then just perform your new ajax call if it has.  It would seem you must already have most of the code written and you only need to add an `if` statement to compare the tokens...?

Comment: I am trying to do same logic as you mentioned, but I am struck at, I am not able to return the data of  setinterval of fucnction in reactjs for one ajax, for eg. in my testing code var token2 = setInterval(this.Refresh_token, 10000);

Comment: Add the code you have tried to your question so that we have something to work off of to help provide an answer.  Difficult to understand exactly what the issue is without seeing more code.

Comment: eg. componentDidMount: function(){
        this.Order_list();
        var token1 = this.Refresh_token();
        var token2 = setInterval(this.Refresh_token, 10000);
        if (token1 != token2)    {                                            self.Order_list();  token1 = token2;  }
This above code don't reach upto if section, it just keep rotating at setinterval line

Comment: Better to add your code to the question by editing it, as it is hard to read in a comment.  However, saying that, you are attempting to assign `token2` as the result of the call to `setInterval`, which is not what `setInterval` is returning.  Further, you are comparing that token value after the setInterval call, when you need to be comparing it in your ajax response handler.

Comment: I will update my whole code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the "Refresh_token" component as your controller. It will handle all of the checking token and get the new order when token has changed. The "Order list" should not know when a token has changed, its job is to re-render its view when a new list has arrived.

```js
//Section 1 Starts Here
var Orderlist = React.createClass({
 render: function(){
        var orderlist11 = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.props.list.length; i++){
         var orderItem = this.props.list[i];
         orderlist11.push(
          <div className="card">
           <div className="title">
            Order Number {orderItem.ordernumber} 
           </div>
           <div className="content"> 
            Date & Time : {orderItem.bizorderdate} <br />
             Username : {orderItem.userid}
           </div>
                </div>
            );
  }
        return (
            <div> {orderlist11} </div>
        );
  }
});
 
////// Section 1 ends here
 
 
var RefreshToken = React.createClass({
  
    getInitialState : function(){
        return {
            token : -1 , //Or anything that is not a token.
            orderlist : []
        }                      
    },

    refreshTimer : null,
    componentDidMount : function(){
     this.get_order_list(); //Get the intial order list
        this.refreshTimer = setInterval(this.refresh_token, 10000); //Call to check the new token every 10s
    },
     
    refresh_token : function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/order/refresh",
            headers: {
                Accept : "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            success: function (resp){
             var newToken = resp;
             console.log(newToken); //it give the value of refresh eg. ["20150925313"] //Assume this will give the new value of the order list changed.
                if(newToken != this.state.token){
                    this.setState({ token: newToken});
                    this.get_order_list() //Get the new list when token has changed.
            //      console.log(this.state.resp);
                } 
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },

    get_order_list : function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/order/list/10/1",
            headers: {
            Accept : "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            success: function(orderlist) {
             //      console.log(orderlist);
             //      console.log(this.state.orderlist);
             this.setState({orderlist: orderlist});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
         }
        });
    },

    render: function(){
     return <Orderlist list={this.state.orderlist} />
    }
});
 
React.render(
  <RefreshToken  />,
  document.getElementById('list_of_orders')
);
```